# "Target" dropdown in Internal Link options not populating in Sitecore 8.2 Update 3

Tags: sitecore-client

[image]

The only thing that works for me, is the line commented out in the screenshot below:

Comment the InsertLinkViaTreeDialog

[image]

I Tried lots of solutions provided in the community but didn't work for me except the one below:

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/863

https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/general-link-field-bug-with-internal-links-opening-in-new-window/

https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/06/20/sitecore-8-general-link-field-internal-link-target-doesnt-render-properly/

http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2015/06/sitecore-8-general-link-field-target_23.html

Any Clue? Which direction should we move with?

Comment: is it a RTE field or a General Link ?

Comment: This is general link

Answer (score 3):

Add the Versions for the below childs of Targets /sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets

Then check the Internal Link, you will see 2 entries in Target dropdown.

After that remove the latest version and again check the Internal Link. You can see those Targets dropdown values

Comment: Siva Kumar's answer is correct, but it doesn't explain why it works. In reality, you have to reindex the Core database, and when you create and delete a version from an item, that item is reindexed. Try reindexing your core database and see if it works, it did for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve this issue by rebuilding Sitecore_core_index from Control Panel > Index Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue in Sitecore 10 version. Fixed by re-indexing the tree */sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets* in core db.