# "Target" dropdown in Internal Link options not populating in Sitecore 9.3 for Non Admin Users

Tags: content-editor

We are facing the below issue with Sitecore 9.3 where the Target dropdown is blank for non admin users and it has the correct 3 values for the content authors where Administrator checkbox is checked.
We have tried the below but with out success.

- Rebuild Core index
- Adding new versions of /sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets and child items
- ["Target" dropdown in Internal Link options not populating in Sitecore 8.2 Update 3](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/target-dropdown-in-internal-link-options-not-populating-in-sitecore-8-2-update)

The only thing that worked for me is commenting the following line in Sitecore.Speak.Applications.config

But the Adding Email to the link option is missing in the "internal link.aspx" so due to business restrictions, we could not use the other dialog.

```
<override dialogUrl="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Internal%20link.aspx" with="/sitecore/client/applications/dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog" />
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

If it works correctly for your Administrators, then items should already be in the core index.

As the issue you described is only happening for non-admin users, I suspect that the problem is in Sitecore access permissions. Please try switching to the Core database and going to the folder `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets`. Then check "Security Details" of the folder and its child items. By default this folder does not have any specific security rules and access to it is allowed to all users with the role **sitecore\Sitecore Client Users**.

You can also use the [Access Viewer](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/view-the-access-rights-of-a-security-account.html) tool to see the final access rights for any user or role.

[image: Security details]

The reason why it starts working when you comment out the `<override>` line in the config is because it tells Sitecore to switch to the older version of the dialogue where all "Target" dropdown options are hardcoded and, therefore, they are the same for all users including Administrators.

Comment: Hello Anna, Thanks for checking the issue and providing the detailed explanation. But we have already verified the security access rights for the folder "/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets" and I have even created a dummy user and have provided read write access to this folder with subitems. Still the options are not showing up for the user, we have tried this with multiple users by updating the security rights for user and role basis.

Comment: Let me know, if you could provide any more information to find the root cause.

Comment: That's interesting, please could you check if you see a request to `/-/item/v1/sitecore/shell?search=&searchConfig=%7BABF3B317-CFCA-441A-815A-F810AB1EDB0D%7D&sc_content=core&language=en&payload=full` in the browser Network tab when you open the "Insert Link" dialogue? If yes, what is in the query string and response for this request? It should return 3 items for the "Targets" dropdown. And if you do not see this request, are there any JavaScript errors in the browser console?

Comment: I have verified this in network tab, the request is visible on network tab for both admins and non-admins. For Admins, the response has totalcount:3, resultCount:3 and the complete response. For Non admins, totalCount is 3, resultCount:0 and items array is blank.

Comment: @DeepakJena please could you also check if the request URL is exactly the same for both admin and non-admin users? Just trying to narrow down where the difference is coming from.

Comment: Yes the Request url is exact same. The same query returns result when logged in as admin and no results when logged in as non admin user. The issue has to be related to security access but I could not find any special security rights for the folder or child items for "/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets".

Comment: Please could you try the following: 1. Go to the Access Viewer in Sitecore (you can add the parameter `?sc_content=core` to the URL to switch to the core DB). 2. Select one of the non-admin users at the top. 3. Navigate in the tree to one of the child items of `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets`. 4. Select the Read access rule and screenshot the details that appear on the right. This is how it looks on my Sitecore instance https://imgur.com/XqXH22C, how does it look on your website?

Comment: Here is the screenshot for read access for the item on the environment. 
https://imgur.com/k1OIgfM
I have tried to add a user specific rule on the folder, but same results

Comment: Thanks, your permissions look good. Another reason why these items can be filtered out is "Language Read" access on the language item. Please can you do a similar check in the Access Viewer, but for your language item in the folder `/sitecore/system/Languages`  (this is in the Master DB) and access rule `Language Read` (this column can be enabled using the Columns button at the top)? Example: https://imgur.com/L4XVtSE

Comment: Hello Anna, I have verified the language item "Language Read" access. Its the exact same as yours and seems correct. https://imgur.com/a/6eVTZCB
Let me know, if you could think of any other scenario.

Comment: Thanks for checking Deepak. If you can reproduce this issue on your local site or in a non-production environment, you can try to troubleshoot it using Search.log. You will need to switch the logging level to "INFO" for Search log and compare the Solr queries that are logged when you test it with admin vs non-admin users. You can also try executing these queries directly in Solr to compare results.

Comment: I have already verified the Search.log, the queries generated for admin and non-admins are exact match. Some how sitecore is filtering out the results after getting the response from solr based on security access rights..